# Eclipse does not allow access to static interface method in external jar from another workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

- There are two eclipse workspaces, *Workspace A* and *Workspace B*.
- In *Workspace A*, there is a project with an interface defining a public static method:

  ```
  package workspacea;

  public interface Foo {

    public static String sayHello() {
      return "Hello, world!";
    }
  }
  ```
- I then exported the entire project from *Workspace A* to a *.jar-File, using Export → Java → JAR file and default settings.
- In *Workspace B*, a class should access the static method previously defined:

  ```
  package workspaceb;

  import workspacea.Foo;

  public class Bar {

    public static void test() {
      String msg = Foo.sayHello();
    }
  }
  ```
- The previously exported *.jar from *Workspace A* is added to the Java Build Path using Project Properties → Java Build Path → Libraries → Add External JARs...

After following these steps, the line `Foo.sayHello();` **does not compile**:

```
Unresolved compilation problem: 
This static method of interface Foo can only be accessed as Foo.sayHello
```

From my understanding, it should compile (it recognizes the `Foo` interface perfectly fine). The funny thing is that it **compiles fine if both projects are located in the same workspace** (still using the *.jar library and not a project dependency).

Eclipse offers a quick-fix, which has no effect (at least not on the code).

[image: Eclipse quick-fix tool-tip]

**What is happening here? Why does the code not compile?** Is this an Eclipse bug? If so, is there a fix for it?

I am using Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) Build 20150219-0600 and used Java 8 in *Workspace A*, Java 7 in *Workspace B*.

Additional note: I can only reproduce this by using an `interface`. Using an `abstract class` and the same method works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was caused by using a pre-Java-8 version in *Workspace B*. There is no bug in Eclipse or Java, Java 7 and below just do not support static methods in interfaces. Java just gives a misleading error saying the static method could be referenced, even though it technically cannot be as it is not available in Java 7 or below.

Comment: .. would be nice if you could tell how you fixed it (e.g. to tell maven to use java 8 )

Comment: @Alex Properties | Java Build Path | Libraries | (select) JRE System Library | Edit | select environment to be Java 8

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen because I had created a new Maven project, and it had by default set the compiler level to 1.5.

Switched it to 1.8 and resolved this.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this:

Change compiler level and hit Okay!![image: ![Java-1.8 or above]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhgvA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Switched it to 1.8 and resolved this issue
Follow the below steps:

1. Right click on Java Project
2. Go to Properties
3. Java Build Path
4. Libraries
5. JRE System Library
6. Edit
7. Select Java 1.8